# how to limit number of connections to IBM MQ

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq, connection-pooling

I have a Spring Boot based messaging app sending/receiving JMS messages to/from IBM MQ queue manager.
Basically, it uses `MQConnectionFactory` to organize connection to IBM MQ and a `JmsPoolConnectionFactory` from `messaginghub:pooledjms` to enable JMS connection pool, which is removed from MQConnectionFactory in IBM MQ 7.x

The app uses two different appoach to work with JMS. A "correct" one runs a `JMSListener` to receive messages and then sends a response on each message using `JmsTemplate.send()`. And there is a second "troubling" approach, where the app sends requests using `JmsTemplate.send()` and waits for response using `JmsTemplate.readByCorrelId()` until received or timed out.

I say troubling because this makes JMS sessions last longer if the response is delayed and could easily exhaust IBM MQ connection limit. Unfortunately, I cannot rewrite the app at the moment to the first approach to resolve the issue.

Now I want to restrict the number of connections in the pool. Of course, the delayed requests will fail but IBM MQ connection limit is more important at the moment, so this is kind of appropriate. The problem is that even if I disable the JmsPoolConnectionFactory, it seems that `MQConnectionFactory` still opens multiple connections to the query manager.

While profiling the app I see multiple threads `RvcThread: com.ibm.mq.jmmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection@12433875[...]` created by `JMSCCMasterThreadPool` and corresponding connections to the query manager in MQ Explorer. I wonder why there are many of them in spite of the connection pooling is removed from MQConnectionFactory? I suppose it should open and reuse a single connection then but it is not true in my test.

Disabling "troubling" `JmsTemplate.readByCorrelId()` and leaving only "correct" way in the app removes these multiple connections (and the waiting threads of course).
Replacing `JmsPoolConnectionFactory` with  `SingleConnectionFactory` has not effect on the issue.

Is there any way to limit those connections? Is it possible to control max threads in the `JMSCCMasterThreadPool` as a workaround?

Comment: The chapter [Calculating the number of channel instances](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=application-sharing-tcpip-connection-in-mq-classes-jms) says: "Number of channel instances = (jms_connections + jms_sessions) / SHARECNV_value". Maybe this helps you to understand the channel instance allocations from Spring/JMS.

Comment: Is there a way to limit their count on the Spring/JMS side? I am ok with "connection pool exhaused" error instead of uncontrolled connection increase...

Comment: For listeners use [concurrency](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html#concurrency--) property, for JmsTemplate use [CachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html#setSessionCacheSize-int-). You don't get exceptions, but MQ resource usage is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Because it affects other applications your MQ admins probably want you to not exhaust the overall Queue Manager's connection limit (`MaxChannels` and `MaxActiveChannels` parameters in `qm.ini`). They can help you by defining an MQ channel exclusively used by your application. By this, they can limit the number of connections of your application with the `MAXINST` / `MAXINSTC` channel parameter. You will get an exception when this number is exhausted which is appropriate as you say. Other applications won’t be affected anymore.